# Delegate method in the set delegate object not responding

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates, uitableview

I have a somewhat similar concern with this question [a custom delegate method inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067769/a-custom-delegate-method-inside-didselectrowatindexpath).

However, in my case before getting to the delegate object which is a UIViewController named BarCodeViewController, I should first pass by 2 view controllers from the initial view controller which is the CardViewController which is a table view controller. I'm setting the delegate object for my custom delegate through this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CardDetailsViewController *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cardDetails"];

    Card *selectedCard = [self.myWallet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // I want this selected card to be accessible until the user clicks another card or during end of program.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];

    [self.delegate cardWalletViewController:self withCurrentCard:selectedCard];

    [self setDelegate:self.barCodeVC]; // barCodeVC is declared in CardWalletViewController.h as @property (nonatomic, strong) BarCodeViewController *barCodeVC;

    if (self.delegate) {
        NSLog(@"delegate is not nil");
    }

}
```

and this is how I instantiate the view controller which I set as the delegate object

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setBarCodeVC:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myBarcodeVC"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And in my delegate object, which is the BarCodeViewController I implement the delegate method

```
#import "CardWalletViewController.h"
@interface BarCodeViewController () <CardWalletDelegate>

@end

@implementation

- (void)cardWalletViewController:(CardWalletViewController *)sender withCurrentCard:(Card *)currentCard 
{
    Card *myCurrentCard = currentCard;


    NSLog(@"This is my current card: %@", myCurrentCard);
}

@end
```

I think I am able to set my delegate object, but then the delegate method is not being implemented for I don't see in the console the NSLog(@"this is my current......"); when I reach the BarCodeViewController.

Advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a standard use for delegate and it's hard to tell what you really want to happen.  but, it looks like your code...

```
[self.delegate cardWalletViewController:self withCurrentCard:selectedCard];
[self setDelegate:self.barCodeVC];
```

Is making the call on whatever the "old" delegate is (before setting it to barCodeVC).  Are you really trying to make the call on the "new" delegate?  Should it be...

```
[self setDelegate:self.barCodeVC];
[self.delegate cardWalletViewController:self withCurrentCard:selectedCard];
```

**EDIT**

What I am saying is that you are sending a message to the delegate in this line...

```
[self.delegate cardWalletViewController:self withCurrentCard:selectedCard];
```

and THEN you are setting the delegate to barCodeVC

```
[self setDelegate:self.barCodeVC];
```

So, the message is actually being sent to whatever the delegate was set to before it was set to barCodeVC (another view controller, or nil, or...).  Maybe that's what you want to happen, but it looks suspicious.

Comment: What I wish to happen is to pass the selectedCard to the BarCodeViewController, which is the barCodeVC (edited my post). With regard to your insight, I didn't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Edit: just added a comment beside [self setDelegate: self.barCodeVC];

Comment: Got that. Ahm I placed the [self setDelegate:selfBarCodeVC]; to the viewDidLoad method so that I could set my delegate immediately. However, the delegate method is still not responding once I get to the BarCodeViewController. Note that, before I could go to the BarCodeViewController, I'd pass by another table view (named CardDetailsViewController) after clicking a table cell in the CardWalletViewController. Then once I clicked on another table cell (referring to CardDetailsViewController), a new view controller will be presented which is the PerksDetailsViewController. (continued below...)

Comment: A button is present in this PerksDetailsViewController that once it is pressed, the BarCodeViewController will then be pushed. 

Now when I reach this BarCodeViewController, I expect to see the log in my console saying NSLog("This is my current card %@", myCurrentCard), an indication that the delegate method is responding.

Comment: Yes, and I may be misunderstanding the code, but again, it looks like you are calling the delegate method BEFORE you are setting the delegate to be the BarCodeViewController.